# Why a Tensorflow fit call with a validation generator uses the same samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, data-generation

I am trying to fit a NN on some data that I stream to my model with generators. I use generators both for the train and for the validation samples. I expected that the fit method would iterate over both the train and the validation datasets, however I saw that the model uses the same validation samples over and over again. That is, the validation generator resets every epoch.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def gen(use):
  while True:
    for i in range(10):
      print(use + f' using mat of {i}')
      X = (np.ones(40)*i).reshape(10,4)
      y = np.ones(10).reshape(-1,1)
      yield (X,y)

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator = lambda:gen('train'),
                                               output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                               output_shapes = ((10,4), (10,1)))

dataset_val = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator = lambda:gen('validation'),
                                             output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                             output_shapes = ((10,4), (10,1)))
dataset_train.batch(2)
dataset_val.batch(2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 10))

model.compile(loss = 'mse')

history = model.fit(dataset_train,
                    steps_per_epoch = 1,
                    epochs = 5,
                    shuffle = False,
                    verbose = 2,
                    validation_data = dataset_val,
                    validation_steps = 1)
```

Note that I use tensorflow 2.2.0-rc3 (the google colab default version).

In this code, my generator produces a 10 by 4 martix of some number *n* that changes in each iteration. This matrix represent my input features. The labels here are just a vector of ones (10 by 1). What I would have wanted to get in this toy example is that for each epoch *i*, the features matrix would be a matrix of *i*s. The output I recieve:

```
Epoch 1/5
train using mat of 0
validation using mat of 0
1/1 - 0s - loss: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.9937
Epoch 2/5
train using mat of 1
validation using mat of 0
1/1 - 0s - loss: 1.5841 - val_loss: 0.9909
Epoch 3/5
train using mat of 2
validation using mat of 0
1/1 - 0s - loss: 3.8616 - val_loss: 0.9902
Epoch 4/5
train using mat of 3
validation using mat of 0
1/1 - 0s - loss: 7.7457 - val_loss: 0.9906
Epoch 5/5
train using mat of 4
validation using mat of 0
1/1 - 0s - loss: 13.1401 - val_loss: 0.9915
```

So the training generator works as I expected, but the validation is stuck on 0.

Is there a way to iterate also over the validation dataset?

Comment: This is probably by design. Using different validation sets would result in noise and be counter-productive to what a validation set is used for.. Specify `validation_steps` accordingly and as noted in the Keras doc: `It should typically be equal to the number of samples of your validation dataset divided by the batch size. `

Comment: Thanks. I still think that in many cases you may want the validation set to be dynamic as the training set, for example, in time series. Suppose that you could train on data over a time window (say a month) and evaluate the model on the week that follows this window.

Comment: No this makes no sense to me. Either use all that is available or use a fixed subset but don't introduce random noise. If you switch the validation set midway in the training you don't actually know what you are measuring anymore. Did the error improved due to the training or because we switched the set? What your doing is akin to Cross-Validation without the benefits or reasons of Cross-Validation.

Comment: If you really want to use subsets for whatever reason then do multiple runs with different subsets which are kept fixed during training.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Tensorflow extracts the validation data at once and uses it for all the epochs. Refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L766). Hence, that is the reason for your output.

I think, even in the documentation it is inline with this, i.e. there is no mention about the generators in `validation_data`.

From Documentation:

> **validation_data:** Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data. validation_data will override validation_split. validation_data could be:
>
> - tuple (x_val, y_val) of Numpy arrays or tensors
> - tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) of Numpy arrays
>     dataset
>
> For the first two cases, batch_size must be provided. For the last case, validation_steps could be provided.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. In the documentation the third case is a dataset (it appears in your quote as a part of the second case). For a dataset, one should specify `validation_steps`. It is unclear from the documentation if the model will use the same samples repeatedly or will draw the specified amount of steps each epoch, as it does with the training dataset. I don't see why would the `fit` method accept a validation generator if it uses the same samples... what point is there for a generator if the model actually ignores its' mechanism?

Comment: since, it is common that validation set is always constant. They didn't mention anything about that I guess.